# Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION'

Tags: phonegap

I have create one app using phonegap. I have used Cordova Social Sharing plugin when we build using https://build.phonegap.com/ generate error

```
Error - A plugin you are using requires a preference: ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION
```

Answer (score 3):

see [build fails on PGB with Error - A plugin you are using requires a preference: ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305672/build-fails-on-pgb-with-error-a-plugin-you-are-using-requires-a-preference-an)

Your question is missing stack trace and other details. However, the plugin

```
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
```

has an issue and fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/mj/projects/benara-sales-client/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 266

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

To fix, you may install v5.4.0

so remove the plugin and the correct version

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-x-social-sharing
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-social-sharing@5.4.0
```

Hope this helps.