# build fails on PGB with Error - A plugin you are using requires a preference: ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I've updated the cordova-plugin-print (by katzer)to v0.8.0 but it fails when building with PhoneGap Build. It throws this error

> Error - A plugin you are using requires a preference:
>   ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION
>
> Where: Build file
>   '/var/gimlet/tmp/47255016036300/3460831/project/build.gradle' line:
>   276
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project'.
>
> Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION' for object
>   of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Is anyone willing to help?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing stack trace and other details. However, the plugin

```
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
```

has an issue and fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/mj/projects/benara-sales-client/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 266

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

To fix, you may install v5.4.0

so remove the plugin and the correct version

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-x-social-sharing
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-social-sharing@5.4.0
```

Hope this helps.